# The cost of big assets folder

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, assets

I have a lot of lazy modules in the application and each module has its own graphic files (mostly SVG's).
What is the best way to store the SVG files? Should I put them all in the assets folder?

Another option is to store them as base64 in the module so those images will be load only when the module is loaded.

I want to know what is the best way to store those files and if I store them all in the assets folder will there be a cost for it (like a big loading time when entering the app) or does the assets folder is loaded lazily by its nature?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to host the images elsewhere with a CDN?

Comment: Better to keep in assets folder. Also, the images will be loaded only when the browser tries to render it.

Comment: Yes, @WillAlexander. I want to save an HTTP call.

Comment: If I store the images in base64 at the code itself then it will be lazy (because it is in a lazy module) and there will be no server call to get the image